# Vote reversal behaving different on mobile / Opera Mini

Tags: support, voting, mobile-web

I noticed that when using SO on Opera Mini (which works almost frigtheningly well btw) vote reversal (i.e. un-downvoting an edited post in my case) does not work the way it does on the desktop site.

On desktop, when I click the downvote button (already hightlighted) a second time, it will undo my downvote, so things appear as if I never voted. In Opera Mini, when I tap the downvote button again SO instead tells me that my downvote is now locked until the next edit (that will probably never happen).

This just happened to me the second time and although it is not a real drama, I think it would be nice if I could "spread more love" instead of being a grinch, also on mobile.

Is this a bug in the mobile site, a problem of Opera Mini, or is this designed to be that way?

**EDIT**: Ok, I'm sorry, my bad. I just didn't quite get the restrictions on vote reversals by now apparently: a quick test on up- and instantly unup-voting a post in Opera Mini just worked the way it should. Apparently the bug is with me. Thanks for the clarification though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your vote in one of two circumstances:

- Less than 5 minutes has passed
- The post has been edited since your vote was cast

The logic for all of this is identical (there is no "mobile" for this, it's all the same voting code), so the behavior between mobile and desktop both have the same rules above.  If you *really* want to retract your downvote, applying a small edit to the post to do so isn't unheard of...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try reverting the vote 5 or more minutes after you voted?

If yes then you have to wait for the next edit.

Comment: Would this mean, that if I downvote a post at 12:00, the post gets improved at 13:00, I won't be able to undo my downvote at 14:00? (That's pretty much the situation I encountered)

Comment: @m90 You _should_ be able to undo your downvote, not sure why you shouldn't be able to.

Comment: Also, the "locked in" message shows the time you last voted, @m90. If that is indeed, say, 12:00 then a screen capture might be nice to prove things! (But then: that message is sent by the server after clicking the button, and like Nick says: that is the same server side code as used on the regular websites.)

Comment: @Arjan, atm I have the feeling that I just didn't get how vote reversal *really* works, but I'll keep that in mind and will try to do the next reversal on mobile so I'll have a definitive result.